# Salesforce equivalent of "SELECT DISTINCT"?

Tags: salesforce, soql

I want to know what all the existing values of a field are.

In SQL that would be something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT foo
FROM bar
```

How might I do this with salesforce's SOQL?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `Group by`

```
SELECT foo
FROM bar
GROUP BY foo
```

eg:

```
SELECT Status
FROM Case
GROUP BY Status

1|New
2|Assigned
3|In Progress
4|In Progress Known Issue
```

Answer (score 2):

In other case, you can using:

```
SELECT Id, foo, col_Sort, another_multiple_col
  FROM bar
ORDER BY foo, col_Sort
```

After that, You can using Map with key: "foo".
Add all data query to this map. So you will have the distinct record. Just using

```
yourmap.get('your_key').
```

to get result

Answer (score 2):

While using Group By, try to use `COUNT(ID)` also.

**Case #1:**

```
List<AggregateResult> lst1 = [SELECT foo FROM bar GROUP BY foo];
```

Though if this query returns just `15` records after processing `10000` records, all the records it processed to get the `AggregateResult` will be counted against the 50000 SOQL rows Governor Limit.

`Number of query rows: 10000 out of 50000`

**Case #2:**

```
List<AggregateResult> lst2 = [SELECT COUNT(ID), foo FROM bar GROUP BY foo];
```

In this case, only the final result rows (that is `15`) will be counted against the 50000 SOQl  rows Governor Limit.

`Number of query rows: 15 out of 50000`